# C# Why is StreamWriter writing empty lines after each time it writes to the file?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I know this is a bit of a "Day one" question, but I'm still having trouble understanding why my Stream writer is writing empty lines after each time it writes

```
namespace PostFinder
{
    class HistorySaver
    {
        public static void Save(string item, string path)
        {
            StreamReader sre = new StreamReader(path);
            string historyList = sre.ReadToEnd();
            sre.Dispose();
            StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(path);
            sr.WriteLine(historyList+sr.NewLine+item);
            sr.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `WriteLine` adds newline. Try `Write`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sr.WriteLine(historyList+sr.NewLine+item);
```

The `.WriteLine()` method puts an end-of-line character after the contents you pass to it. If you don't want that character, use `.Write()`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like all you are wanting to do is append text to a file, so there is really no need to open a streamreader to read in the existing contents and then write them back out with your new content.

You can use the below to do all that you want in one step.  If the input path file doesn't exist it will create a new one, and if it already exists it will just append your new item.

```
namespace PostFinder
{
    class HistorySaver
{
    public static void Save(string item, string path)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(path, item + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to remember this.